# Does robocopy /move actually "move" directories when on same local hard drive?

Tags: directory, robocopy

The MSDOS `move sourceDirectory destinationDirectory` command when `sourceDirectory` and `destinationDirectory` are on the same hard drive just moves some links around, and doesn't actually copy all the files to a new location, and then delete them.

Does `robocopy sourceDirectory destinationDirectory /mov` act like the MSDOS `move` command when `sourceDirectory` and `destinationDirectory` are on the same hard drive?

All the robocopy documentation I've been able to find, has not been clear on this point.

I'm running 64bit Windows7 in case that matters.

Comment: Why would you think it wouldn't? If they're on the same drive, all that has to be done is update the file system to reflect the new starting location, and nothing else changes. (And why would it matter?)

Comment: Documentation says, "/MOV : MOVe files (delete from source after copying)."  It matters, because I have 60+Gig in directories that I'm moving around.

Comment: There's no reason to think that they would have **unoptimized** the optimization in `move`, is there? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robocopy copys the data first, then deletes the previous files even if they are on the same hard drive.  It does *not* do an optimized move.  This was tested on a Windows 7 machine.